# Error while using colSums with tab-delimited file

Tags: r, statistics

I'm new at R and I'm currently trying to get some statistical data from a file. It is a large set of data in txt tab-delimited file. While importing the file I had no problem and all of the data is shown correctly as a table in rstudio. However, when I'm trying to make any sort of calculations using colsums,

```
> colSums("Wages and salaries")
```

> Error in colSums("Wages and salaries") :  'x' must be an array of at
> least two dimensions

I do receive an error

> `x' must be an array of at least two dimensions`.

"Wages and Salaries" is the name of the column I'm trying to get the sum of.
Using V1 or any other column name that was created by r gives me another error

```
> colSums(V2)
```

> Error in is.data.frame(x) : object 'V2' not found

The way I'm importing the file is

```
 rm(list=ls())
  filename <- read.delim("~/filename.txt", header=FALSE)`
> is.data.frame(filename)
[1] TRUE
```

This gives me a matrix type data table with rows and columns the same way excel would show me the data.

The reason I'm trying to get a sum of all of the numbers in column is to later get sum of several different columns.

I'm very new at R and I could not find an answer to my question as most of the examples are using just a very small set of data that was created in the r.

Comment: How do you import the file ? What is your data called? `colSums` expects a dataframe/matrix and you should not use `""` around it. For eg see, `colSums(mtcars)`

Comment: please run through some basic r tutorials, the column sums of a character string doesn't make sense, so it's not even clear what your intentions were

Comment: You are probably looking for `sum(filename$V2)` or  `summary(filename)`.

Answer (score 0):

In R you can access a column in 2 ways:

filename["Wages and salaries"]

or

filename$`Wages and salaries`

So, please try :
colSums(filename["Wages and salaries"])